# Header Text Not Wrapping JQM

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

My header text looks like:

```
My Hea....
```

I want it to read

```
My HeaderHereTodayAndIsTooLong
```

What do I have to change in the jquery mobile framework/css to make this render correctly?

```
   <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
     <h2>My HeaderHereTodayAndIsTooLong</h2>
      <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { partnumber = ViewBag.PartNumber })" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="info">Home</a>
     </div>
```

Comment: That displays [correctly for me](http://jsfiddle.net/), can you reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Jack I updated the header my first example wasnt long enough to see the effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your h2 tags in a div, if you want the text to appear in the centre still then add a text-align style to the container div just made:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <h2>My HeaderHereTodayAndIsTooLong</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: To have your button appear on the right, remove the text-alignment and just apply some styles to your header to position it how desired, rough example:

```
<div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div>
        <h2 style="font-size:0.8em;margin-left:10px;width:70%;">My Header Here Today And Is Too Long</h2>
    </div>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home", new { partnumber = ViewBag.PartNumber })" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="info">Home</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my markup, I realized I forgot a to add a link button located on the right of the header which makes this solution not render correctly

Comment: Just CSS styling, have included a rough example which you can get the idea from... The original answer was hopefully what you was looking for to get around the truncation of the text. Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried that but what happens is the class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="info" jqm uses to make the link look like a mobile button goes away I think because its in a div tag

Comment: Hi Nick, I have edited it again with the button outside the div containing the header, seemed to work ok for me. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can try just overriding the margin styles that JQM adds to the `hx`, of course that will only buy you a bit more space, eventually if your header text is to long it will still overflow (you can of course override those styles to).
for example

```
.lrMarg0
    {
        margin-left:0px !important;
        margin-right:0px !important;
    }


     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h2 class="lrMarg0">My HeaderHereTodayAndIsTooLong</h2>
        <a href="#"  class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="gear" data-role="button">Next</a>
      </div>
```